# imprimir datos de un objeto al seleccionar un elemento

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

¿Como podría acceder a los demás datos que tengo en un objeto en Jquery?

Al hacer click en el boton, PHP regresa un array en forma de JSON el cual se enlista en una una serie de titulos en un Div.

Necesito que al hacer click en cualquiera de los parrafos que se crean en el for me permita imprimir en otro DIV los datos referentes a ese titulo.

Ejemplo:
este es un parrafo que genera for al recorrer el objeto JSON.

No puedo acceder a la BD

Al dar click me gustaria que despliegue los datos complementarios del objeto, descripción, urgencia etc.

Solo eh podido ejecutar un alert al dar click a cualquier p que genera el for pero no se como acceder a los demás datos relacionandos con los parrafos del for.

```
'use stric'
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#actualizar").on('click',function(){
       var data="";
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'php/solicitudesPendientes.php',
            data:{"data":data},
            success:function(data){
            var myObj=JSON.parse(data);
              var title=document.querySelector("#request");

              for(var i in myObj){
                var p=document.createElement("p");
   p.append(myObj[i].id_solicitud +"  "+ myObj[i].titulo_solicitud);
                title.append(p);
              }//for
              $('p').on('click',function(){
  //aqui necesitaria que se complemente los datos referentes al "p" que se selecciono.
              });


            }//success

        });//Ajax

    });
});
```

Actualmente aquí se imprimen los resultados del FOR:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>solicitudes pendientes</legend>

<input type="button" id="actualizar" value="Actualizar">
<br><br>
<div class="pendientes" id="request"> <!-- Aquí las solicitudes -->  
    <tr>ID</tr>
    <tr>Titulo</tr>

 </div>

</fieldset>
<hr>
```

y lo que sigue es que al dar click en cualquier parrafo en otro div me complemente los datos del titulo, como la descripcion, urgencia, etc.

Answer (score 0):

no se si entendi bien tu pregunta pero aca te dejo una solucion bastante generica :

1)  para acceder a los datos que te faltan simplemente tenes que conocer la extructura de tu `JSON`, si no lo conoces podes simplemente hacer un `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` en el success de la petición ajax.

2) si los datos JSON no tienen un id, te aconsejaria ponerlos para semplificarte la vida.

aca te dejo un ejemplo funcionante echo en Javascript vanilla :

- creacion de un objeto JSON
- tomo el div donde quiero agregar mis "preguntas" en este caso.
- ejecuto un for para rellenar el div con mis preguntas
- doy un listener al documento para que me detecte los click
- si el target del evento es un elemento `p` tomo su `ID`
- visto que el elemento tiene un id numerico (pero viene tomado como string), le hago un `parseInt` y le quito 1 para obtener el indice del elemento y del objeto. **PD: si no usas id podes obtener el mismo resultado con un `e.target.index`)**
- y agrego otro elemento conteniente el dato que falta, que en este caso seria la respuesta.

```js
var jsonObj = { "preguntas": [
                {
                  "pregunta": "como estas?",
                  "respuesta": "bien, gracias",
                   "id": 1
                },
                {
                  "pregunta": "donde vivis?",
                  "respuesta": "en mi casa",
                   "id": 2
                },
                {
                   "pregunta": "que haces?",
                   "respuesta": "nada",
                   "id": 3
                }
              ]};
 var div = document.getElementById("preguntas");
 for (i = 0; i < jsonObj.preguntas.length; i++){
     let p = document.createElement("p");
     p.setAttribute("id", jsonObj.preguntas[i].id);
     let texto = document.createTextNode(jsonObj.preguntas[i].pregunta);
     p.appendChild(texto);
     div.appendChild(p);
 }
 
 document.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
     if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "p"){
        let elemento = document.querySelectorAll("p")[parseInt(e.target.id)-1];
        let resp = document.createElement("span");
        let texto = document.createTextNode(" "+jsonObj.preguntas[parseInt(e.target.id)-1].respuesta);
        resp.appendChild(texto);
        elemento.appendChild(resp);
     }
 });
```

```html
<div id="preguntas">

</div>
```

espero que te sea de ayuda.